# Inconsistent execution of executeScript in Cordova inAppBrowser on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm having some trouble with some inAppBrowser behavior in my cordova app. Here's the code:

```
var codePass = fooCode;
var executeScriptFunc = function(event) { 
  ref.executeScript({
    code: codePass
  }, function (value) {});
  ref.removeEventListener('loadstop', executeScriptFunc);
};

var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(fooObject.link, "_blank", "location=yes,enableViewportScale=yes");
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', executeScriptFunc)
```

The strange thing here is that the code works perfectly every time when emulated. It opens the browser and executes the script no problem. But when I try it on my actual iPhone device, it doesn't always work. The script executes maybe every other time. But it's never even that consistent.

Both the emulator and iPhone are using iOS 9.3.4. Any ideas?

Comment: In trying to diagnose this a bit more I discovered that the loadstop listener is also being fired on exit. This is not happening in the emulator, only on the device, and again only on iOS, In this case 9.3.4. Similar behavior with loadstart, though exit seems to be working fine.

Comment: Ok, I have a workaround, but it's not ideal. It seems to work every time on iOS devices when I remove the cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine Plugin. Given that this helps optimize the app, it seems this isn't a great scenario. WKWebView seems to be the issue so may be related to [CB-11136](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11136?jql=component%20%3D%20%22Plugin%20InAppBrowser%22%20AND%20project%20%3D%20CB) and [CB-10698](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10698?jql=component%20%3D%20%22Plugin%20InAppBrowser%22%20AND%20project%20%3D%20CB).

Answer (score 4):

If the site inside the inAppBrowser happens to be served via HTTPS, the callback for `executeScript()` will not work if the site employs a `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP response header that does not contain the `gap:` or `gap-iab:` schemes for the `default-src` directive.  These are needed because [execution of the callback function on iOS relies on an iframe that gets added to the page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9445?focusedCommentId=14705853&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14705853).

You can check whether this is the root cause for the problem by opening Safari’s Web Inspector for the inAppBrowser—it has a separate Web Inspector instance, independent of the parent application that opened it—and look out for a corresponding error message in the console.  Note that you should open the console before `executeScript()` is run, or otherwise you might not get the error message.

Comment: what 'corresponding error message'? Is it a Content-Security-Policy warning?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure also that you don't have other event handlers firing at the same time during your polling.

I had multiple pollers all firing every second and that's when I ran into the issue.

After changing the polling time so they all fired at different times, the issue went away.